# the fundamental exact sequence associated to a closed space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be an algebraic variety. If $Y\subseteq X$ is a closed subset, then we can equip $Y$ with a structure of algebraic variety $(Y,\mathcal O_Y)$. The function  $i:Y\rightarrow X$ is the usual immersion, moreover if $i_*\mathcal O_Y$ is the pushforward of $\mathcal O_Y$ through $i$, we have the following surjective morphism of sheaves:

$\mathcal O_X(U)\rightarrow i_*\mathcal O_Y(U):=\mathcal O_X(U\cap Y)$ such that $s\mapsto s|_{U\cap Y}$

Clearly $i_*\mathcal O_Y$ is an $\mathcal O_X$-module and the kernel of the above morphism, called  $\mathcal I_{Y|X}$, is a sheaf of ideals, so an $\mathcal O_X$-module. Finally we have the fundamental exact sequence of $\mathcal O_X$-modules associated to $Y$:

$$0\longrightarrow \mathcal I_{Y|X}\longrightarrow \mathcal O_X\longrightarrow i_*\mathcal O_Y\longrightarrow 0$$
I have two question, one conceptual and one more technical:

1) Why is it so important considering closed subspaces of $X$? For example if $U\subseteq X$ is open, then $(U,\mathcal O_X|_U)$ is an algebraic variety so one can costruct the fundamental sequence for $U$.

2) In some texts there is the identification of $i_*\mathcal O_Y$ with the sheaf $\mathcal O_Y$. How can I prove this identification?

Comment: (2) is simply an abuse of notation. I do not recommend it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $X$ be an integral scheme and let $Y$ be a non-empty open subscheme of $X$. $X$ is irreducible, so $Y$ is dense in $X$. I claim the induced homomorphism $i^\flat : \mathscr{O}_X \to i_* \mathscr{O}_Y$ is monic but not necessarily epic. Indeed, the claim is local on $X$ and $Y$, so we may take $X$ to be affine and $Y$ to be a distinguished open subscheme of $X$. But then all we have is a localisation of an integral domain, and this is always injective but not necessarily surjective.

---

The point is that there isn't *one* notion of subscheme which gives rise to open and closed subschemes; rather, there are *two*.

*Open* subschemes are a special case of the following construction: if $X$ is a locally ringed space and $Y$ is *any* subset of $X$, we can make $Y$ into a locally ringed space by pulling back $\mathscr{O}_X$ along the inclusion $i : Y \hookrightarrow X$. Unfortunately, there's no guarantee that $(Y, i^{-1} \mathscr{O}_X)$ is a scheme even if $(X, \mathscr{O}_X)$ is.

On the other hand, the definition of a *closed* subscheme depends a lot on the scheme structure. If $Y$ is a closed subset of $X$, that means $Y \cap U$ is closed in $U$ for every open subset $U$ – but we know that closed subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ are homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} A / \mathfrak{a}$ for some suitable ideal $\mathfrak{a}$, and in essence the structure of $Y$ as a closed subscheme of $X$ is *defined* so that we have an exact sequence
$$0 \longrightarrow i^{-1} \mathscr{I}_{Y \mid X} \longrightarrow i^{-1} \mathscr{O}_X \longrightarrow \mathscr{O}_Y \longrightarrow 0$$
or equivalently, so that we have the "fundamental exact sequence":
$$0 \longrightarrow \mathscr{I}_{Y \mid X} \longrightarrow \mathscr{O}_X \longrightarrow i_* \mathscr{O}_Y \longrightarrow 0$$

---

But the story for varieties is more subtle. For the purposes of this discussion, I mean "variety" in the sense of a reduced scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$. Because varieties have enough closed points, the structure sheaf of a variety $X$ is isomorphic to a subsheaf of the sheaf of continuous functions $X(k) \to \mathbb{A}^1(k)$. (Henceforth, I will pretend non-closed points don't exist.) Thus, there is a canonical way of restricting regular functions on (any open subset of) $X$ to any (not necessarily open or closed!) subset $Y$ of $X$. If $Y$ is open, this recovers the open subscheme structure, and if $Y$ is closed, this recovers the closed subscheme structure.

Let's look at this more closely. We define $\mathscr{I}_{Y \mid X}$ to be the subsheaf of $\mathscr{O}_X$ consisting of those regular functions which vanish on $Y$, i.e.
$$\mathscr{I}_{Y \mid X} (U) = \{ f \in \mathscr{O}_X : \forall y \in Y . \, f (y) = 0 \}$$
and we define, for each open subset $V$ of $Y$,
$$\mathscr{O}_Y (V) = \varinjlim_{U \supseteq V} \mathscr{O}_X (U) / \mathscr{I}_{Y \mid X} (U)$$
This is a sheaf because $Y$ is quasicompact. (Every subset of $X$ is quasicompact!) If $Y$ is open, then $V$ is open in $X$, so we are taking the direct limit over a directed system with a terminal object – hence $\mathscr{O}_Y (V) \cong \mathscr{O}_X (V) / \mathscr{I}_{Y \mid X} (V) \cong \mathscr{O}_X (V)$ in this case.

For $Y$ closed something weird happens as well. Let $U$ be an open affine subset of $X$. Then, $V = U \cap Y$ is a closed subset of $U$ and an open subset of $Y$. Suppose $f \in \mathscr{O}_X (U)$ does not vanish on $V$. Then, the Nullstellensatz implies $f$ is already invertible in $\mathscr{O}_X (U) / \mathscr{I}_{Y \mid X} (U)$ – and this implies that the directed system is constant! In particular, we get $i_* \mathscr{O}_Y \cong \mathscr{O}_X / \mathscr{I}_{Y \mid X}$.

In general, however, we don't get anything nice. There is a natural left exact sequence of groups
$$0 \longrightarrow \mathscr{I}_{Y \mid X} (U) \longrightarrow \mathscr{O}_X (U) \longrightarrow \mathscr{O}_Y (U \cap Y)$$
and therefore a left exact sequence of sheaves on $X$:
$$0 \longrightarrow \mathscr{I}_{Y \mid X} \longrightarrow \mathscr{O}_X \longrightarrow i_* \mathscr{O}_Y$$
We have just seen that this extends to a short exact sequence when $Y$ is closed. When $Y$ is open and $X$ is irreducible, the homomorphism $\mathscr{O}_X \to i_* \mathscr{O}_Y$ is monic but in general not epic. (Consider a point $x \in X \setminus Y$: the stalk of $i_* \mathscr{O}_Y$ at $x$ gives the fraction field of the local ring $\mathscr{O}_{X, x}$.)